# How can install android AVD not in default place

Tags: android, directory, android-virtual-device

I download eclipse and android in D drive.At time of installation ADT plugin in eclipse using this link: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  I found an error notice: AVD not install because of my AVD is not in C:/user/documentandsetting/... folder that means it is not in default one. My AVD is in D: drive. How can I install AVD is not in default folder?

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding a new environment variable which points to your android installation in D: drive

Start Menu > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings  > Environment Variables

Add a new user variable  that points your android directory: 
Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME Variable value: D:/